# Mysql Query - Query to show Itens that are from Actual date to the Max of 15 days ago

Tags: datetime, mysql

This is a bit "confused" question for those who don't now advanced SQL...

However. I want your help to do a query. Its simple but I'm not sure how to do it.

I want the query to do something like this.

I want her to

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE date....`

The date condition its only to show items that have a date to the MAX of 15 days past the actual date.
PS: The data column is a `datetime` type.

Does somebody now how can i accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   table1 t
where  DATE(t.mydate) <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) 
ORDER BY t.mydate DESC;
```

Comment: Didn't workout..
But never mind. I've use other way.

Thanks any way.

Comment: @KGTM:  feel free to explain exactly what didn't work.  Someone will probably be able to help you with that.

Comment: Never mind... I had to change some of the items.. Its was a tipping error.
Thanks it worked.